# Module malfunction

Tags: java, class, methods

In this class, i am adding the method addstudent() and the parameter here should have at least 8 numbers and have first digit zero. I am always getting false when I run the program.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Module {

    public static final int MAX_STUDENTS = 300;

    private String module;
    private int id;
    private String lec;
    private String code;
    private int sem;
    private String modCode;
    private String group;


    public Module() {
        module = "module";
    }

    public Module(String modCode) {
        this.modCode = modCode;
    }

    public boolean addStudent(int id) {  

        String s_id = Integer.toString(id);
        int idlength = s_id.length();
        char fdigit = s_id.charAt(0);
        boolean b1 = fdigit == 0;

        if ((idlength >= 8) && (b1)) { 
                return true;
        }
            else {
                return false;

            }

    }
}
```

This is the test class -

```
import java.io.*;

public class ModuleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

     Module Software = new Module("0123456789");

        Software.addStudent(012344567);

        System.out.println(Software.addStudent(012344567));

    }
}
```

Comment: Change your boolean method parameter to String and then pass the id.

Answer (score 3):

When you store a number in an `int` variable, there is no concept of leading zeroes. For example, 1 and 01 are represented exactly the same and are therefore indistinguishable.

If you want to preserve leading zeros, you should pass the `id` into the function as a `String`.

While we are on the subject, it is worth noting that `012344567` is an [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) literal, which I am pretty sure isn't what you intended (read about octal literals in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)).

Finally, to check whether a `char` variable contains the digit zero, you should compare with `'0'`, not with `0`. The latter is equivalent to comparing with `'\u0000'`, which is the [Unicode NULL character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm).

Comment: Also comparing fdigit==0 woudn't return true, since fdigit is a char and has the int value 48 (instead of 0).

Comment: Thanks. But, I changed the int input into a string. Shouldn't that convert the int value to a string ?

Comment: @Archit: By that time you've already lost the leading zeroes.

Comment: What if I am not allowed to take the input as a string. What should I do if I can only take an integer as an input?